# iOS9 Contacts Framework get identifier from newly saved contact

Tags: ios, swift, cncontact, cncontactstore, contacts-framework

I need the identifier of a newly created contact directly after the save request. The use case: Within my app a user creates a new contact and give them some attributes (eg. name, address ...) after that he can save the contact. This scenario is working as aspected. My code looks like this:

```
    func createContact(uiContact: Contact, withImage image:UIImage?, completion: String -> Void)
    {    
       let contactToSave = uiContact.mapToCNContact(CNContact()) as! Cnmutablecontawctlet
       if let newImage = image
       {
          contactToSave.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 1.0)
       }
       request           = CNSaveRequest()
       request.addContact(contactToSave, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)
       do
       {
          try self.contactStore.executeSaveRequest(request)
          print("Successfully saved the CNContact")
          completion(contactToSave.identifier)
       }
       catch let error
       {
         print("CNContact saving faild: \(error)")
         completion(nil)
       }
  }
```

The Contact Object (uiContact) is just an wrapper of CNContact. 
In the closure completion I need to return the identifier but on this time I have no access to them, because he is creating by the system after the write process. 
One solution could be to fetch the newly saved CNContact with predicate

```
public func unifiedContactsMatchingPredicate(predicate: NSPredicate, keysToFetch keys: [CNKeyDescriptor]) throws -> [CNContact]
```

but this seems to me like a bit unclean because this contact could have only a name and more than one could exist. Something like a callback with the created identifier would be nice. But there isn´t. 
Is there a other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

This may be a little late but in case someone needs this.

By using the latest SDK (iOS 11), I was able to get the identifier just by:

```
NSError *error = nil;

saveReq = [[CNSaveRequest alloc] init];
[saveReq addContact:cnContact toContainerWithIdentifier:containerIdentifier];

if (![contactStore executeSaveRequest:saveReq error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save, error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}
else
{
    if ([cnContact isKeyAvailable:CNContactIdentifierKey]) {
        NSLog(@"identifier for new contact is: %@", cnContact.identifier);
        // this works for me everytime
    } else {
        NSLog(@"CNContact identifier still isn't available after saving to address book");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 4

This is the way to get contact id when creating contact

```
    do {
        try store.execute(saveRequest)
        if contactToAdd.isKeyAvailable(CNContactIdentifierKey) {
            print(contactToAdd.identifier) // here you are getting identifire
        }
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
    }
```

Comment: Works also for swift 5

Comment: This isnt working for me, as I find when saving a contact to a Google address book, that the identifier I saved with seems to change after it is saved. Annoyingly this means that if i add the contact to a group, it disappears when i refetch the group as it no longer exists. HOWEVER the newly created contact is now found in the address book, with a different identifier, and I could add that to the group. I am baffled as to why

Comment: At that time it was working for me, at this stage I was also mad for this feature. Thank you to reach here, please provide your answer once you get it.